# Скопируйте одну структуру в другую

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Есть две структуры:

```
type Foo struct {
    A string
    B int
}

type Bar struct {
    A string
    B int
}
```

Как скопировать одну в другую? Я хочу скопировать одну структуру в другую, без `reflect` и без непосредственного копирования:

```
foo := Foo{
    A: "a",
    B: 1,
}

bar := Bar{
    A: foo.A,
    B: foo.B,
}
```

Comment: На англоязычном SO есть [несколько примеров](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603296/copy-from-one-struct-to-another-struct-in-go), но большинство из них имеют дело с небезопасными операциями, не гарантирующими результат.

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать "наследование" структур.

```
type Foo struct {
    A string
    B int
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{
        A: "a",
        B: 1,
    }
    
    bar := Bar{foo}

    fmt.Println(foo)
    fmt.Println(bar)
}
```

теперь структура Bar содержит все из структуры Foo. т.о. инициализировать одну иожно через другую, как в примере выше

**UPDATE**
если структуры отличаются полями, то вот решение

```
type Foo struct {
    A string
    B int
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
    C string
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{
        A: "a",
        B: 1,
    }

    bar := Bar{foo, "my custom field"}

    foo2 := bar.Foo

    fmt.Println(foo)
    fmt.Println(bar)
    fmt.Println(foo2)
}
```

Comment: Наследование не годится. Нашёл: https://play.golang.org/p/zhhXOTbk1b . Но такой подход не годится, если хотя бы одно поле не совпадает.

Comment: укажите в вопросе, что поля отличаются.